# how to use --add-opens param to get rid of illegal reflective access warning?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what I pass to --add-opens to make this warning go away. Does anyone know?

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sleepycat.je.utilint.JVMSystemUtils (file:/home/.m2/repository/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.jar) to method sun.management.BaseOperatingSystemImpl.getSystemLoadAverage()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sleepycat.je.utilint.JVMSystemUtils

Comment: It is explained in the `java` command reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html.  Use --add-opens to open modules, use --illegal-access=... to help identify modules that need to be opened.

Comment: Also note that you are using an old version of  Berkeley DB JA.  The current one is 7.5.11.  This *may have* fixed this, though the public changelog doesn't say so.  If not, you could try to contact the vendor (Oracle!) and ask them when they plan to support Java 11.  ('Cos I can't find any announcements ...)

Comment: thanks @StephenC wow, thats such a trip, its like getting help from my doppleganger

Comment: It is fixed in the latest Berkeley DB jar , its just that your name is my name irl, funny.